# ¿Cómo podría cambiar un permalink de una plantilla en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Soy novato en wordpress y me gustaría saber como cambiar un permalink que viene por defecto en una plantilla. En concreto se trata del enlace de los posts de las galerías (es una página de fotografía). Y la url incluye el nombre de la plantilla cuando abro cualquiera de las galerías. Os pongo el ejemplo

http://miweb.es/avalon_td_gallery/fotografia/

Y lo que me gustaría es que fuese:

http://miweb.es/galeria/fotografia/

Comment: Tienes que ir a Escritorio -> Ajustes - > Enlaces permanentes y allí elegir la opción deseada. Si quieres que te aparezca sólo fotografía, eliges la penúltima opción: **Nombre de la entrada**  y le das al botón **Guardar** y listo.

Comment: Tengo marcada la opción de Nombre de la entrada pero cuando abro una de las galerias (gallery posts) me las mete dentro de "avalon_td_gallery" que es un link de la plantilla supongo. Lo que quiero cambiar es justo eso. Gracias por responder tan rápido.

Comment: Tal vez sea un Custom Post o algo así. Si aparece en las taxonomías, podrías editar el permalink como en las categorías o en los posts. Si no es un Custom Post, entonces lo que necesitas es __editar la tabla de redirecciones__. Busca un plugin que haga eso, en inglés es _Redirections_.

Comment: Esa no es una mala opción de WordPress y no te recomendaría que la cambies. Lo normal es que en tu sitio tengas organizadas las URL incluyendo la categoría a la que pertenece cada página. ¿No será que estás tratando un post como si fuera una página y de ahí el problema ?

Comment: <protesta>Parece una forma super intrusiva de hacer publicidad de su theme </protesta>... ¿Puedes confirmar sí `avalon_td_gallery` es un Custom Post Type? ¿Tiene menu principal en la admin de WP?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tendrías que modificar las rewrite rules de lo que evidentemente parece un custom post type que usas. Te recomiendo el plugin [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) que te mostrará todas las reglas que tienes y le eches un vistazo a la clase [WP Rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

Te dejo un ejemplo que no es exactamente lo que necesitas, pero te puede dar un norte. Para un proyecto que estoy haciendo necesitaba modificar la url de los autores, osea, en lugar de misitio.com/author/fulano-de-tal, necesitaba misitio.com/profile/fulano-de-tal:

```
function my_rewrite_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    // Rewrite the author base rule
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'profile';
}
add_filter( 'init', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
```

Seguramente antes que funcione tendrás que actualizar la configuración de los Enlaces Permanentes...

Saludos.